# Lenovo bootable USB

Tags: system-installation

I have followed [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#9) to create a bootable USB Stick on Windows.  I have installed the image twice, but cannot seem to get it to boot.  I don't think anything is wrong with the image.  Just not sure how to get the Lenovo to boot the USB drive.  Have tried <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>.  I start by using the Windows menu to shut down.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Is there a way to test the USB Bootable drive?  I am not really sure how to trouble shoot this one.  Sorry.  I am sure this is a stupid question, just been stumped on this for most of the day and getting frustrated.

Comment: There's novo button you can click to boot to USB.

Comment: @Jim novo button?

Comment: This --> https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/HT062552.

Comment: @Jim in case the external resource is later removed, The "novo button" might be found on Lenovo Idea Laptops.  It is a either a small button or pinhole with a backwards arrow icon next to it resembling an upside down U.  It enables you to enter Lenovo onekey recovery if the PC fails to boot normally. Under "NOVO Button Menu", you are provided to perform system recovery, enter BIOS or configure boot menu.